# Jmeter generate random domain name

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-plugins

How can I generate random domain name in using JMeter?

This is what I tried:

```
Random Variable

VariableName=domainName
OutputFormat=00000.com
MinumumValue=Aa
MaximumValue=Zz
SeedForRandomFunction=__RandomString
```

Comment: put up some random domain name examples you want.

Comment: the domain name could be any one valid or even invalid domain name would do eg `google.com, aoogle.com, xyhncfr.com , jsdfjhkd.com, dsnfjkds324.com`
and if it could be even more random then it would be great like example `jdsfkjhsd.in ,jfklf.us ,hfkjhgjkhg.de` where the part after . should should be within {de,com,in,en,us}

Comment: @NachiketKate anything how should i get it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Though you have not mentioned which type of random domain names you want, I have considered some examples,

```
domain_00001.com
domain_03000.com
```

etc.

This can be created like,

[image]

In Beanshell preprocessor this code should yield the desired output,
change it accordingly as per need.

```
import java.util.Random;

public class MyDomainRandomGen {

    private static final String CHAR_LIST ="abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";
    private static final int RANDOM_STRING_LENGTH = 10;

    public String generateRandomDomain(){

        StringBuffer randStr = new StringBuffer();
        for(int i=0; i<RANDOM_STRING_LENGTH; i++){
            int number = getRandomNumber();
            char ch = CHAR_LIST.charAt(number);
            randStr.append(ch);
        }

        String[] domains = {"de","com","in","en","us"};

        int idx = new Random().nextInt(fruits.length);
        String random = (fruits[idx]);

        randStr.append(random)

        return randStr.toString();
    }
}
```

Comment: thank you for the answer, yes but in this i was not possible to generate random alphabets

Comment: and the domains i have mentioned in the comments

Comment: Apology for old answer. Actually I wrote it before your comments. For random alphabets its very difficult through random variable. But through Beanshell processor its possible.

Comment: Beanshell great i will give it a try and let know

Answer (score 0):

got it using this pluging

http://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/ParameterizedController/?utm_source=jmeter&utm_medium=helplink&utm_campaign=ParameterizedController

like this

```
 domainName=${__RandomString(${__Random(00,20)},ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ1234567890,)}.com
```

Comment: not exactly but still the .com part is not random enough it should be random within a set like {.com,.en,eu,.org,.net}, maybe Beanshell might help me with that